Can this stain job be salvaged?
Can this stain job be salvaged??
I bought a bed for my son and it is made of Baltic birch plywood. I wanted it to have a more finished natural wood look, so my husband stained it. I do not like the outcome whatsoever. The weathered oak stain definitely has more gray than I expected and is very dark. I’m regretting the color and the oil based product. Two days later and my head still hurts. I’m scared to let my son sleep in his bed! I’m feeling extremely discouraged.
Can this be salvaged? Re-stained? Painted? Stripped? Is there any chance covering it with a water-based poly will help the color? I would like to sand the entire thing right away but it’s winter here and we need to work inside. We have a shellac finish but didn’t use it yet in case the color can be fixed. Would sealing help with the odor? Any advice or suggestions would be helpful!





Hi, welcome to StackExhange. First let me put your mind at rest, the solvent odour will dissipate in time and eventually there will be no smell whatsoever. But in the winter, with limited airflow, this might take a long while (if you do nothing). "We have a shellac finish but didn’t use it yet in case the color can be fixed. Would sealing help with the odor?" Yes plus shellac will actually directly help with your main problem because it's not colourless. I presume it's a natural shellac, so likely to be orangey in the container and will add an 'amber' tint which might be just the ticket.

This sort of thing is exactly why the advice is to always test stain (or any finish really) on a scrap or unseen surface before proceeding to application over the entirety of a project. Worth bearing in mind for the future, and also for now — if you want to go that route, test the shellac on the back of a piece if possible, before committing to applying it everywhere. BTW shellac is a challenging finish to apply by brush for the newbie/beginner, highly highly advise watching some vids first and practising on the undersides of components before tackling the visible surfaces.

Thank you! I planned to test a piece but my husband did the staining while I was taking a nap. He believed he was doing something nice for me, but I woke up to something I didn’t like :/

We purchased Bulls Eye Shellac Traditional Finish & Sealer - CLEAR. It’s a spray can. Open to suggestions on a different product if you believe there’s a better option! @Graphus

Zinsser's shellac is what I expected, since it's one of the few shellac products out there and by far the most common. It's clear in the sense you can see through it but not colourless (think stained glass). It's a good product, but I don't know that it'll do what you want here; but being the natural colour of shellac it will 'warm' the colour up some. However do be aware you wouldn't typically use shellac on any high-use product as a final finish as it's not super tough, and more critically it's not water-resistant. You can however have complete confidence it's not toxic should it be chewed.

Anyway, if you do go the route of painting this you don't need to prime or otherwise 'seal' the wood first, irrespective of paint type, as long as you give the stain plenty of time to dry — a week at minimum but preferably longer if you go with a waterbased paint. If you go with a durable oil-based enamel you should be able to paint pretty much immediately, but waiting a couple of extra days wouldn't hurt.

We probably won’t paint it until the spring/summer. Will use shellac in the meantime. 5 days later and I can still smell it. We keep the windows open for a couple hours with a fan but not any longer because of the cold. Thank you very much for your responses and advice!!!

Very welcome, that's what we're here for! "5 days later and I can still smell it" That's quite normal I assure you (very much so in the winter, indoors). Even in ideal drying conditions it can take perhaps 10 days to two weeks for the bulk of the odour to dissipate, such that you're not really aware of the smell. For every trace to be gone — where even if you put your nose right on the surface and sniff — the rule of thumb is it takes a month, in 'normal' conditions of approximately 60-70° F and moderate humidity. Cold slows the curing reaction so it takes longer.

Any suggestion on how to go about painting it? If we went this direction, should we still use a shellac sealer first? There’s really no reason to use the shellac if you plan to paint it. Get a good primer and apply 2 coats then paint it to whatever color you desire.

Can this be salvaged? Re-stained? Painted? Stripped?   Considering that you think the stain is already too dark there is no way to make the stained area lighter by adding more stain. Since stain is basically a pigment added to a medium to penetrate into the wood pores, there is also no way to strip the stain.  You can of course, paint it and this may be the easiest solution for your project.
Is there any chance covering it with a water-based poly will help the color?  A clear poly finish will not lighten or obscure any unevenness or darkness in the finished appearance and a finish with more stain will only contribute to the darkness problem.
I would like to sand the entire thing right away...  Sanding plywood can be very challenging since the top layer of wood is very thin and it would be very easy to sand too deep.  Sanding the surface may lighten its appearance a bit, but it will be very difficult to do so uniformly.  If you want to try, take Graphus' advice in the comments and first experiment in an obscure surface area.
BTW, of course it is a bit "Gray" since it is written right on the cross beam :)

Any suggestion on how to go about painting it? If we went this direction, should we still use a shellac sealer first?

This comment could easily be posed as a separate question and may get some informative answers.  You can provide a link to this original question to cross reference them
